# tag <form> deletes part of code after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a kind of form like this:

```
 <form>
    <input class="form-control" id="searchField" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="searchUserButton">SEARCH BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

When I press on SEARCH BUTTON (I'm using jquery to figure out when button is pressed), I call an ajax request and I print some information from json file in a html file BUT something strange happens:

I can't see the result! Otherwise if I remove the form tag (so I have just input and button element) everything is ok, I can see all the data...so what happens?! How should I do in the right way an ajax request with jquery (so when button is pressed)?

Jquery:

```
    $("#searchUserButton").bind("click", function () {
    searchData();
    });
```

Ajax:

```
function searchData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'data/file.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: showData,
        error: function () {
            // FAIL
            alert("ERROR!");
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Can you also post your JS code too?

Comment: You're probably not doing a `e.preventDefault();` when the button is clicked. If in form tags, a submit button will cause the page to reload by default. Without form tags, this will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Change your click event to this:

```
$("#searchUserButton").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchData();
});
```

Your problem seems to be what I had assumed in the comments above.

A `type="submit"` button inside of a `<form>` will cause the form to process and the page to reload, whereas without `<form>` tags, this will not happen. By doing `e.preventDefault();`, you're instructing the button to *not* submit the form, and instead do your `searchData()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<button type="submit" ...
```

to

```
<button type="button" ...
```

otherwise the form submits anyways and your page reloads regardless of your click handlers.